# Window.open with apostrophe in the file name

Tags: javascript, c#

How can one open files with apostrophe in the file name. I'm currently using

```
<div onClick="window.open('file'sname.jpg);">
Wont open
</div>
```

With exactly zero success.

I've tried all the different suggestions on various questions I found but nothing worked, 
Escaping to `\'`, `%27`, `&apos;`, `&#39;`

I even tried `Uri.EscapeDataString()`

Comment: Using `&apos;` instead of the apostrophe can do the trick.

Comment: @IvánPérez I meant to write &apos in the original question, why would I escape single quotation with double quotation. IT didn't work either way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mid posting I managed to figure it out, and it wasn't mentioned anywhere so I decided to post the Q&A

Double Escape does the trick.

```
\\'
```

I escape it in my C# code so the end result in the HTML while inspecting is:

```
<div onClick="window.open('file\'sname.jpg);">
Wont open
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't mention you needed to escape it in C# first.  Makes a big difference in your question.